# How old is the software engineering site?

Tags: discussion, websites

I have seen there are a lot of questions on `stackoveflow` compare to the other stackexchange sites like this `software engineering`.

I just wondering if this maybe depends on the age of this sites? 
I'm also wondering how old is the Code Review site.

Comment: The number of questions on a site depends not only on the age of the site, but also on the number of people interested in that topic. And it seems there seem to be far fewer people interested in professional software engineering than in coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange maintains a list of all public sites with some basic stats (including site age) here: http://stackexchange.com/sites.

According to that list, Software Engineering is 6 years 7 months old and Code Review is 6 years 3 months old.

Comment: Worth noting, that the name "softwareengineering" for this site is much newer, it used to be called "programming"